# unaccessible files in lost+found

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4, gnu, fsck

(This in principle the same as [question 15800742 on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800742/chmod-cannot-read-directory-permission-denied), but the answer that it got, as well as miscellaneous other answers I have found on the Internet, have not worked for me.)

After a filesystem crash and fsck, I ended up with a /lost+found directory with some files (both regular files and directories) I have not been able to figure out how to do anything useful with.

System info:

```
toomas ~ # uname -a
Linux toomas 4.10.0-38-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 10 16:32:20 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@toomas ~ # chmod --version | head -1
chmod (GNU coreutils) 8.25
root@toomas ~ # lsb_release -d
Description:    Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia
root@toomas ~ # id -u
0
```

The filesystem is mounted at /mnt:

```
root@toomas ~ # mount | grep /mnt
/dev/sdb1 on /mnt type ext4 (rw,relatime,block_validity,delalloc,barrier,user_xattr,acl)
```

I'm taking #16792 (which happens to be a directory) as an example:

```
root@toomas ~ # d="/mnt/lost+found/#16792"
root@toomas ~ # ls -ld $d
d--S-ws-w- 2 90907680 1161865838 4096 Nov 13  2215 /mnt/lost+found/#16792
```

(The UID and GID, while conspicuously huge, should be legal: the greatest UID that adduser accepts on my system is 2^32 - 2 = 4294967294, and the IDs wrap to zero at 2^32.)

Changing permissions fails:

```
root@toomas ~ # chmod 755 $d
chmod: changing permissions of '/mnt/lost+found/#16792': Operation not permitted
```

Changing ownership fails:

```
root@toomas ~ # chown root $d
chmod: changing ownership of '/mnt/lost+found/#16792': Operation not permitted
```

lsattr/chattr do not help either:

```
root@toomas ~ # lsattr -d $d
lsattr: Permission denied While reading flags on /mnt/lost+found/#16792
```

Trying to chattr anyway, just in case:

```
root@toomas ~ # chattr -i $d
chattr: Permission denied while reading flags on /mnt/lost+found/#16792
```

What else could I try to view and/or delete these files?